# How put and call toolbar_main.xml in Content_main.xml?

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I am new in android and have several questions, and decided to ask them here, hope you help me, thank you in advance.

First i have  problems with when i make a new project i chose make activity with navigation drawers, in default the android studio make `app_bar_main.xml` , `toolbar_main.xml` and `content_main.xml` and involve  `content_main.xml` in app_bar_main.xml so it makes i have toolbar in each of pages, but i want to put the `toolbar (app_bar_main.xml)` in `content_main.xml` but when i do it my app force close and appear lots of errors, any body have he right **answer with sample code**?

The reason for doing this is to customize my content specially when i use a dialog with out toolbar title, i search and test lots of sample code but none of them works in this case, I select "no title" in app-theme in `dialog.xml` but the dialog shows with empty place of toolbar title.

Thanks for your negative score instead of helping

.

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ....>

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

.
**toolbar_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout .....>    
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"  ... />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"... />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    //content
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

.
content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout  
    ......
    android:id="@+id/mainContent" 
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use include tag `<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>` in main_content.xml to include toolbar in main_content.xml